# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_$$_REQUIRE(_dependencyMap[6], "react-native-picker").Picker.Item')

Tags: javascript, react-native

everyone!
while using picker I just encountered this error:

TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_$$_REQUIRE(_dependencyMap[6], "react-native-picker").Picker.Item')

Can someone help me?

Comment: Hi @AmmarBaloch, have you managed to find a solution to this? I am also struggling now with it.